# DataGrip and SQLite - Retrieve Information from DB

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I have questions about DataGrip from JetBrains.
Is there any option to get data, ex?
If I want to get the year when a book was published or the total sum of books sold between 1999 and 2005.

Can jeg just get this information without writing any code and the information I need together with getting the code the system used to get the information?

Answer (score 2):

DataGrip is the tool to write SQL queries. The information you need should be retrieved with the help of the query. I may look like this:

```
SELECT year_piblished FROM Books WHERE book_id = 'here_you_paste_the_id_of_the_book'
```

Comment: Thanks, Moscas!
Is there any way to autocomplete this, or do I have to write the whole code?

Comment: The query generator based on a table name will be introduced in DataGrip 2021.1